# How to solve the PLS-00103 error in function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a function that checks whether a number entered is odd or even in PL/SQL.

I created this function but it is showing the compilation error.

code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION YES_EVEN(p_val IN NUMBER) RETURN BOOLEAN AS
v_result BOOLEAN:= FALSE;
BEGIN
    IF (p_val % 2) = 0 THEN
        v_result := TRUE;
    END IF;
    RETURN v_result;
END;
/
```

Error:

[image: Error for the function]

I have tried to solve this but nothing happens.

Comment: Either use MOD() or REMAINDER() function, % is not an operator in PL/SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't `%` but `MOD`, I presume.

```
if mod(p_val, 2) = 0 then ...
```